# Create a function that separates the characters of a word by symbols

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a function where, for example, if I put the word `visual` in the input box I have to select from the ComboBox one of these 3 symbols: `space`, `.` , or `*`, in the output box I want the result of the word `visual` to come out like this: `v.i.s.u.a.l` or `v i s u a l`

[image]

I already know how to output a result that separates the string by a space but I don't know how to do it using a ComboBox with 3 symbols

This is the code I used for separating with a space

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim n As Integer
        Dim str As String = "mis programing II"
        Dim str2 As String = ""
        Dim cc As String
        For i = 1 To Len(str) 
            cc = Mid(str, i, 1)
            str2 = str2 & cc & " " 
        Next
        MsgBox(str2) 
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `String.Join` like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim str As String = "mis programing II"
    Dim str2 As String = String.Join(str.ToCharArray(), ComboBox1.Text)
    MsgBox(str2) 
End Sub
```

I assumed the seperator has been selected in the `ComboBox`. Else, replace `ComboBox1.Text` with the seperator you want to use.

**Update**

Thanks to @JQSOFT, I just confirmed that `String.Join` does not work on Char arrays. Well here's another solution.

```
Dim str As String = "mis programing II"
Dim listX As New List(Of String)
Dim act As Action(Of Char) = Sub(c) listX.Add(CStr(c))
For Each c As Char In str.ToCharArray()
    act.Invoke(c)
Next
Dim str2 As String = String.Join(".", listX.ToArray)
Console.WriteLine(str2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice exercise:

Can be done using `LINQ` as follows:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim str As String = txtInput.Text '"mis programing II" for this example..
    Dim sep As Char

    'Validate your inputs:
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) OrElse
        Not Char.TryParse(cmbSep.Text, sep) Then
        Return
    End If

    'and in one line:
    Dim str2 = String.Join("", str.Split(" "c).
                            SelectMany(Function(x) x.ToCharArray.Append(" "c)).
                            Select(Function(x) $"{x}{If(Char.IsWhiteSpace(x), " ", sep)}")).
                            Replace($"{sep} ", " ").Trim

    MessageBox.Show(str2)

End Sub
```

If you are not allowed to use `LINQ`, then the next snippet will do the same:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim str As String = txtInput.Text '"mis programing II" for this example..
    Dim sep As Char

    'Validate your inputs:
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) OrElse
        Not Char.TryParse(cmbSep.Text, sep) Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim str2 As New StringBuilder

    For Each word In str.Split(" "c)
        For i = 0 To word.Length - 2
            str2.Append(word(i)).Append(sep)
        Next
        str2.Append(word(word.Length - 1)).Append("  ")
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(str2.ToString.Trim)

End Sub
```

Some outputs:

```
m.i.s  p.r.o.g.r.a.m.i.n.g  I.I  
m^i^s  p^r^o^g^r^a^m^i^n^g  I^I  
m*i*s  p*r*o*g*r*a*m*i*n*g  I*I  
m-i-s  p-r-o-g-r-a-m-i-n-g  I-I  
m_i_s  p_r_o_g_r_a_m_i_n_g  I_I   
m i s  p r o g r a m i n g  I I
```

Comment: thanks for this code its a new way to do it very appreciated , i executed it and it worked perfectly